# Give a scheduled jenkins job temporary priority

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a busy Jenkins server with many big matrix jobs being built all the time. Working with another job can be really annoying if you want instantaneous results... Is there an option to give a job temporary priority for just one build so it skips the queue and gets built on the next available executor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin) and add your jobs with higher priority than the rest